# IOS : How to handle "Cancel" button on Alert pop up, when Location services turned off

Tags: ios

I am using location services in my application. When I run the application with location services OFF, It gives me a pop up saying "Turn on Location services to allow to determine your location" with two buttons "Settings" and "Cancel".

If I tap on Settings, it takes me to Settings app. But If I tap on "Cancel" nothing happens.

I want to detect the touch event on "Cancel" button. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: your question is good

Answer (score 1):

You don't have direct access to that event, sadly.

Comment: Thank you Cuevas, Can I disable or override the default settings alert when location services is turned off from settings

Comment: Yes you can. Before requesting authorization you should check if location services are enabled with `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()`. If they are not you can present your own `UIAlertController`. Unfortunately you cannot send users directly to the location services page in the settings anymore (since iOS 11) but you can send them to your app's settings section with `UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)`.